# luasec fails in 5.1 and 5.2 but OK in 5.3

Tags: lua, openssl, luarocks, luasec

I'm installing LuaSec 0.9 via LuaRocks 3.3.1 with OpenSSL 1.1.1g (via MacPorts).

I use `luarocks install OPENSSL_DIR=/opt/local luasec`

The compilation/installation is successful for Lua 5.1, 5.2, and 5.3

However, when I attempt to use it, I get errors, as follows:

1. Lua 5.1

- `dlopen(/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/ssl.so, 2): Symbol not found: _luaL_checkversion_`

2. Lua 5.2

- `dlopen(/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/ssl.so, 6): Symbol not found: _lua_rotate`

3. Lua 5.3

- success

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is not a `luasec` or Lua issue; it's an issue with LuaRocks after upgrading to the latest version. The situation has been resolved; see [here](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/issues/1209).

Comment: Following the link, was the resolution that you figured out how to use the poorly-if-at-all documented `--lua-dir` and `--lua-version` flags? If so, some description of that solution might be helpful here.

Comment: The precise solution depends on how you build and install your Lua interpreters. I install them in `/usr/local/lua-5.X` where `X` is the minor version. Therefore, a typical `luarocks` invocation (for me) would be something like `luarocks install --lua-version=5.2 --lua-dir=/usr/local/lua-5.2 OPENSSL_DIR=/opt/local luasec` Both flags are needed.